# Visual studio errors in compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting the 2 errors listed below for the line that I have also included below, can someone please tell me why?

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Line:

```
deque; <string> get_image_filename_list(string foldername);
```

Comment: There's a semicolon too many.

Comment: That doesn't look like debugging errors to me, that looks like *compiler* errors, error you get when building the application. And since you can't build the application you can't run (or debug) it.

Comment: `std::deque<std::string> get_image_filename_list(std::string foldername);` and don't forget to include the corresponding header files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, sorry, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @molbdnilo, when I take the semicolon out, the code doesn't work at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, what do you mean by including the corresponding header files?

Comment: @ConfusedChild24 "The" semicolon? Read carefully, then try to remove the other one.

Comment: @ConfusedChild24 `#include <string>` `#include <deque>`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thank you! I had forgotten to #include <decque>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to `include` header at the beggining of your source file:

```
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Then, try to modify your line like:

```
deque<string> get_image_filename_list(string foldername);
```